# unable to move the collar to get to cartridge

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to remove the cartridge to replace it but the collar wont budge doesn't appear to turn and we are the new owners of the property, no tools were left sadly.
There are 4 holes on the inside of the collar around the cartridge is it possible these need a key of sorts to help me screw it out?

Comment: mixer is a Fereno

Comment: A photo would be handy here, as a home owner you will need some basic tools like channel locks, pipe wrenches to do basic plumbing. It is amazing how a lock ring can be stuck and the right tool gets it moving and it spins off.

Comment: There are lots of things containing collars and cartridges, and they are in a broad range of sizes and designs.  So it is difficult for people to give you specific advice without knowing what you're referring to.